# Error: Use of undeclared identifier 'label'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have an `@property` for my `label` in the header .h file but in my .m file. I am trying to do this -
 `[self.view bringSubviewToFront: label];`
But then I get his error: `Use of undeclared identifier 'label'; did you mean '_label'?`

Here's my .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;



@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2;


@end



@implementation ViewController

@synthesize scrollView;



- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    draw1 = 0;

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];



    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);

    // stuff************************************************************************************************************************






    [super viewDidLoad];



            UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];




    NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test26.php";



    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];



    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];



    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];



    [self.view addSubview:webview];

    webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIWebView *webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSString *url2=@"http://google.com";

    NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];

    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];

    [webview2 loadRequest:nsrequest2];

    webview2.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: openMenu];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: scrollView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: label];
```

and here is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *openMenu;
    int draw1;
}
- (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;


@end
```

**How do I get rid and fix my error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `self.label` instead of `label`.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: self.label];
```

Comment: It got rid of my error but now it is not arranging to the front as is the purpose of this code -   [self.view bringSubviewToFront: self.abel];

Comment: Okay, but that's a completely different question and has nothing to do with what you asked. :) If you can't figure that out, then feel free to ask a new question.